# how to make font awsome icon and control in same row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, bootstrap-4, add-on

I have a Font Awesome search text box in grid table header header, but unfortunately below code making control and icon in separate lines. How can I solve this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-left">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Search" class="fas fa-search" aria-label="Search">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/input-group/#basic-example), wrap the two elements in an input group and wrap the icon in an append div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-left">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="fas fa-search" aria-label="Search">

          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">
              <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `display` as `inline-flex` in the `th` tag like `style="display:inline"`.

Comment: Custom CSS is rarely needed for simple layout issues in Bootstrap. The features of the library should be implemented first.